# WorkManager onStopped() method called twice

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I have implemented `WorkManager` in my project. After finishing my task in `doWork()`, I've called `stop(true);` And I've sending a Broadcast to another activity in `onStopped()`. Everything is working fine but the problem is `onStopped()` is being called **twice** (I've tested by applying breakpoints). As a result the `BroadcastReceiver` is also called twice.

I know that the WorkManager is in alpha stage. But I'm not actually sure if this is a bug or I am doing something wrong. Please help. Codes are as follows:

```
public Result doWork() {

    startGettingData();

    stop(true);

    return Result.SUCCESS;
}

@Override
public void onStopped(boolean cancelled) {
    super.onStopped(cancelled);

    Intent intent=new Intent(SERVER_SYNC_BROADCAST);
    intent.putExtra(SYNC_RESULT_MESSAGE,responseCodes);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext()
            .getApplicationContext())
            .sendBroadcast(intent);

}
```

Calling from activity's `onCreate()` just once:

```
WorkUtil.startSyncing(SyncWorker.class);
```

**WorkUtil.java**

```
public class WorkUtil {

private static WorkManager mWorkManager;

public static WorkUtil workUtil;

private WorkUtil() {

     mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();

}

public static WorkUtil getInstance() {

    if(workUtil == null) {
        workUtil = new WorkUtil();
    }

    return workUtil;

}

public static void startSyncing(Class workerClass) {

    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder().build();

    OneTimeWorkRequest someWork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(workerClass)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();
    OneTimeWorkRequest oneTimeWorkRequest = someWork;
    mWorkManager.enqueue(oneTimeWorkRequest);

}

public static void cancelAllWork() {
    mWorkManager.cancelAllWork();
}


}
```

Comment: Is there a chance you are scheduling the work twice?

Comment: Not actually. I'm using `OneTimeWorkRequest`. More codes has been updated. Please check.

Comment: I think there's no need to call `stop(true);`, `return Result.SUCCESS;` is good enough.

Comment: I thought so too. But if I remove `stop(true)`, `onStopped()` is never called. :(

Comment: Does `startGettingData();` use a new thread to fetch data? Also, why do you need `onStopped` to be called? It's supposed to be called when the work wasn't finished...

Comment: No I am not using separate thread as `doWork()` already runs in a separate worker thread. I just want to show a dialog in a different activity when the syncing is finished. That's why I am sending the broadcast to that particular activity when the syncing ends and the worker stops. Is there any better alternative method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to send a broadcast when your work is done.

You shouldn't do it inside `onStopped`, move it to the `doWork` like this:

```
public Result doWork() {

  startGettingData(); // this method should be synchronous

  Intent intent=new Intent(SERVER_SYNC_BROADCAST);
  intent.putExtra(SYNC_RESULT_MESSAGE,responseCodes);
  LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(MyApplication.getContext()
        .getApplicationContext())
        .sendBroadcast(intent);

  return Result.SUCCESS;
}
```

The `onStopped` method is not meant to be called when the work is done, but when it's stopped or canceled.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker#onstopped)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my question is : What is the alternative of `stopSelf()` of `Service` for the `Worker` ?

Comment: You don't need an alternative. If your intention is to save power by stopping the worker yourself - don't worry about it :). The WorkManager is here to save you boilerplate code like this.

Comment: Thanks, by following your solution `BroadcastReceiver` is calling just one time (As expected). In case anyone is interested : The weird part is, I've set e Log print in `onStopped()` which didn't print anything before (When the `sendBroadcast()` was in `onStopped()`). But after moving `sendBroadcast()` Log print starts printing! Found it a little weird.